# Duplication of list while opening multi page using node JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I build an html page linked to a node server.
This page include a hypertext list which is duplicated while other page are opened from the server. I don't want this functionning, the list don't have to be duplicated while other pages are opened.

I test some code, as : list.removeChild  or  list.replaceChild  but the list disappear..
what I want to modify in order to not duplicate the list is :

```
                    var list = document.getElementById("messagesList");
                    socket.on('messageFromServer', function (data) {
                    var item = document.createElement('li');        
                    item.innerHTML = data.network;
                    list.appendChild(item);
                    });
```

Thanks for any help.

Here is the html full code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" >

   <head>
        <meta name="description" content="Interface de Start and Stop du TrainLab" />
        <meta name="Copyright" CONTENT="Alstom" />
        <meta name="expires" CONTENT="never" />
        <meta name="audience" CONTENT="all" />
        <meta name="Language" CONTENT="Fr" />
   
       <title>H M I</title>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
       <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="Design" href="form.css" />
       <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="favicon.ico">
       
       <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
                    

   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="main">
        
            <div id="mainleft">
                    <img src="tom.png" class="favorite img1" title="" alt="  " />
            </div>
            
            <div id="maincenter">
                    
            </div>
            
            <div id="mainright">
                    <h1>  Interface </h1>
            </div>  

            <div id="mainrightright">
                <form action="/switchoff" method="post">
                    <input type="image"  alt="Off Button" src="pictures/off2.png" class="favorite img2" title="OFF" alt="  "/>
                </form>
            </div>          

            
            <div id="mastercenter">
            
                <div id="aboveleft">
                    <p> </p>
                </div>
                
                <div id="abovecenter">
                    <p> </p>
                </div>
                
                <div id="aboveright">
                    <p> </p>
                </div>
            
            
                <div id="left">
                    <p>Doors</p>
                        <div onClick="emit('unlock')" title="Clic to unlock doors" class="favorite styledbutton_unlock" type="submit" id="idunlock" value=""></div>
                    </br>
                        <div onClick="emit('open')" title="Clic to open doors" class="favorite styledbutton_open" type="submit" id="idopen" value=""></div>
                    </br>
                        <div onClick="emit('close')" title="Clic to close doors" class="favorite styledbutton_close" type="submit" id="idclose" value=""></div>
                </div>
                
                
                <div id="center">
                    <p>Light</p>
                        <div onclick="emit('light')" title="Clic to switch on the lights" class="favorite styledbutton_light_minus" type="submit" id="idlight" value=""></div>              
                    </br>
                        <div onClick="emit('lightmore')" title="Clic to switch on the lights" class="favorite styledbutton_light_more" type="submit" id="idlightplus" value=""></div>   
                    </br>
                        <div onClick="emit('micro')" title="Clic to speak with micro" class="favorite styledbutton_speak" type="submit" id="idmicro" value=""></div>        
                </div>              
                
                
                <div id="right">
                    <p>Announcements</p>
                    
                    <ul id="messagesList">
                        <!-- Dynamically generated list of messages sent from the different clients connected to the server -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            
            </div>
            
            <div id="bottom">
                    </br>
                    </br>
                <div id="abovebottomleft">  
                    <form action="/upload" method="post">
                        <input title="Clic to open upload page" class="favorite styledupload" type="submit" id="state" value="Click here to open upload section">       
                    </form> 
                </div>  
                
                <div id="abovebottomcenter">        
                    <form action="/help" method="post">
                        <input title="Clic to open help page" class="favorite styledhelp" type="submit" id="state" value="Help">        
                    </form> 
                </div>              
                
                <div id="abovebottomright">     
                    <form action="/refresh" method="post">
                        <input title="Clic to refresh page" class="favorite styledrefresh" type="submit" id="state" value="Refresh">        
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>  
            
        
        </div> 
        <script defer>
                        var socket = io.connect();
                        
                        var lightmore = document.getElementById("idlightplus");
                        socket.on('etatLightmore', function (state_lightmore) {
                            if (state_lightmore ==1){
                                lightmore.classList.add("lightmore_enabled");
                            }else{
                                lightmore.classList.remove("lightmore_enabled");
                            }
                        });
                        
                        var light = document.getElementById("idlight");
                        socket.on('etatLight', function (state_light) {
                            if (state_light ==1){
                                light.classList.add("light_enabled");
                            }else{
                                light.classList.remove("light_enabled");
                            }
                        });
                        
                        var micro = document.getElementById("idmicro");
                        socket.on('etatMicro', function (state_micro) {
                            if (state_micro ==1){
                                micro.classList.add("micro_enabled");
                            }else{
                                micro.classList.remove("micro_enabled");
                            }
                        });
                        <!-- ici mettre une condition si la liste existe alors ne pas rajouter de liste -->
                        var list = document.getElementById("messagesList");
                        socket.on('messageFromServer', function (data) {
                        var item = document.createElement('li');        
                        item.innerHTML = data.network;
                        list.appendChild(item);
                        });
                        
                        var close = document.getElementById("idclose");
                        socket.on('etatClose', function (state_close) {
                            if (state_close ==1){
                                close.classList.add("close_enabled");
                            }else{
                                close.classList.remove("close_enabled");
                            }
                        });
                        
                        var unlock = document.getElementById("idunlock");
                        socket.on('etatUnlock', function (state_unlock) {
                            if (state_unlock ==1){
                                unlock.classList.add("unlock_enabled");
                            }else{
                                unlock.classList.remove("unlock_enabled");
                            }
                        });
                        
                        var open = document.getElementById("idopen");
                        socket.on('etatOpen', function (state_open) {
                            if (state_open ==1){
                                open.classList.add("open_enabled");
                            }else{
                                open.classList.remove("open_enabled");
                            }
                        });
                        
                        function emit(name){
                        console.log("click")
                            socket.emit("click",name)
                        }
                    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try that : adding " li.remove(); "   at the end of the considered bloc like that :

```
                    var list = document.getElementById("messagesList");
                    socket.on('messageFromServer', function (data) {
                    var item = document.createElement('li');        
                    item.innerHTML = data.network;
                    list.appendChild(item);
                    li.remove();
                    });
```

the result is interesting because there is no duplication of the list while I open 1 or 2 or 3 other pages, but the list is reduce to 1 line. What's wrong ??